# MacBook Air 2018 Kernel panic, can you tell me more?

Tags: kernel-panic

from time to time my MacBook Air 2018 just shuts down and reboots. Here is one log I got:

```
panic(cpu 1 caller 0xfffffff01afab7b4): x86 CPU CATERR detected
Debugger message: panic
Memory ID: 0x6
OS version: 17P4263
macOS version: 19E266
Kernel version: Darwin Kernel Version 19.4.0: Mon Mar  2 20:38:56 PST 2020; root:xnu-6153.101.6~2/RELEASE_ARM64_T8010
Kernel UUID: 3695E9D9-323E-350E-9A6E-65819BE397D7
iBoot version: iBoot-5540.105.2
secure boot?: YES
x86 EFI Boot State: 0x16
x86 System State: 0x0
x86 Power State: 0x0
x86 Shutdown Cause: 0x5
x86 Previous Power Transitions: 0x304050400
PCIeUp link state: 0x68271614
Paniclog version: 13
Kernel slide:     0x0000000012f74000
Kernel text base: 0xfffffff019f78000
mach_absolute_time: 0x5cbbab14a1
Epoch Time:        sec       usec
  Boot    : 0x5e7af5d3 0x000b3b14
  Sleep   : 0x5e7ef287 0x00009b8c
  Wake    : 0x5e7f2874 0x000a4844
  Calendar: 0x5e7f3b6e 0x0004c257

Panicked task 0xffffffe000738e00: 3010 pages, 192 threads: pid 0: kernel_task
Panicked thread: 0xffffffe000a60548, backtrace: 0xffffffe015ffb4b0, tid: 396
          lr: 0xfffffff01a83c764  fp: 0xffffffe015ffb4f0
          lr: 0xfffffff01a83c5c0  fp: 0xffffffe015ffb560
          lr: 0xfffffff01a956e7c  fp: 0xffffffe015ffb610
          lr: 0xfffffff01ae0562c  fp: 0xffffffe015ffb620
          lr: 0xfffffff01a83bf28  fp: 0xffffffe015ffb990
          lr: 0xfffffff01a83c280  fp: 0xffffffe015ffb9e0
          lr: 0xfffffff01b672934  fp: 0xffffffe015ffba00
          lr: 0xfffffff01afab7b4  fp: 0xffffffe015ffba30
          lr: 0xfffffff01af9cbe4  fp: 0xffffffe015ffbaa0
          lr: 0xfffffff01af9eb0c  fp: 0xffffffe015ffbb50
          lr: 0xfffffff01af9c31c  fp: 0xffffffe015ffbbe0
          lr: 0xfffffff01af63780  fp: 0xffffffe015ffbc10
          lr: 0xfffffff01ad72abc  fp: 0xffffffe015ffbc50
          lr: 0xfffffff01ad72340  fp: 0xffffffe015ffbc90
          lr: 0xfffffff01ae10514  fp: 0x0000000000000000
```

Can you maybe see a reason here why this is happening?